# UEFI : os boot manager still has an entry for ubuntu after it's removal

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

I removed Ubuntu 19.0.4 from dual boot with windows 10. But even after the removal, the OS boot manager still shows me two choices. How do I remove the entry for Ubuntu ?

[image: please refer the screenshot]

Comment: It might still be detecting the grub bootloader, even if the OS is removed.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to do this in Windows (though it might be possible with WSL "Windows Subsystem for Linux"), but if you boot the system with an Ubuntu Live CD or usb-stick you might be able to try this:

Run `efibootmgr` command as root to list all entries registered by the bootmanager. In the following example you can see that there are three boot options

```
# efibootmgr
BootCurrent: 0002
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0002,0001,0000
Boot0000  ubilinux
Boot0001  UEFI: Built-in EFI Shell
Boot0002* ubuntu
```

Then use the number for Ubuntu (0002 in the example above) to remove the entry with

```
# efibootmgr -b 2 -B
```

**DISCLAIMER** the above is what I found in `man efibootmgr`. Use at your own risk

Comment: Thanks for the response, just to be on safer side as I'm a beginner to this, I used `diskpart` in windows 10 cmd, removed the entry for ubuntu inside the EFI directory in the `system` partition. It seemed to work.